# Restrict work item fields to specific users in TFS 2010

Tags: xml, tfs, workitem, tfs-workitem

I am using TFS 2010 and I am customizing a work item type. I was wondering, if there is a way to restrict access to fields to users that are members of a group such as:

```
<FIELD name="Created By" refname="System.CreatedBy" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension" />

<FIELD name="Project Manager" refname="CustomField.ProjectManager" type="String" reportable="dimension">
    <HELPTEXT>The name of the project manager.</HELPTEXT>
    <SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="true" filteritems="excludegroups">
        <LISTITEM value="[global]\Project Managers" />
    </SUGGESTEDVALUES>
    <WHENNOT field="System.CreatedBy" value="CustomField.ProjectManager">
        <READONLY />
    </WHENNOT>
</FIELD>
```

**EDIT** Is there a way to restrict a specific user inside a group, for instance: Restrict project manager "John" from changing the field because that work item is not his project, but permit project manager "Jane" to change it because it is her project?

The problem with the code above is that the `value` attribute only accepts a string value and does not recognize a field expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have concluded that you cannot do this. Until I am proved wrong, this is not supported using  TFS 2010.

Answer (score -1):

Not tried this myself, but you should be able to edit this in the work item template (I assume you've already gotten that far since you've pasted some XML from it :)? If not it's under the `Tools > Process Editor` menu) using the VALIDUSER element in your FIELD, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337606(v=vs.90).aspx.

Comment: No that requires that a field's value is a Valid TFS username. (As opposed to a random string).

Comment: In that case is the documentation wrong? It states "VALIDUSER is an optional child element of FIELD (Work Item Type Definition Schema), FIELD (WORKITEMTYPE Element), WHENCHANGED, and WHENNOTCHANGED.

If you do not define one of the optional attributes, all valid Team Foundation Server users and groups will be able to modify the field."

Comment: "If you do not define one of the optional attributes, all valid Team Foundation Server users and groups will be able to modify the field." relates to the "for", "not" and "group" attributes of the VALIDUSER element, this is no different than the question above.

Comment: Can you do this: `<VALIDUSER group="groupName" for="System.CreatedBy" />` ? In other words, can you provide a dynamic userName, here the creator of the work item ?